# I get "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"while using ModelChoiceField in ModelForm in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I want to be able to use ModelChoiceField in my form for my model in django admin. But while the default widget Select works when I customize and add

```
class GalleryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Photo.objects.all(),
                                   widget=forms.SelectMultiple, empty_label=None)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Gallery
```

I get

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

from traceback:

```
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value

 def get_prep_value(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return None
    return int(value)
```

Is there any way to pass string or number to `get_prep_value` or to override it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You can't just turn a single field into one that accepts multiple values just by using a different widget.

Comment: can you paste your entire `GalleryModelForm` ?

Comment: I'm quite new to Django so I do not rule out that my approach is totally misguided:) The gist of it is that I want to upload photos (Photo model, django-athumb, saved to S3) and then create gallery and add multiple previously uploaded photos to this gallery. I've added this to my admin so I can add multiple photos to gallery, since the default widget is Select not SelectMultiple.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) class instead of using a ModelChoiceField with setting a SelectMultiple widget I think.

And thus it would give you the following:

```
class GalleryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=models.Photo.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
    class Meta:
        model = models.Gallery
```

And then, just take care if the form is left empty, Django 1.5 will return an empty queryset, while older versions will return an empty list (ugly).